# My WIFI doesn't work

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-stellar

I have a Samsung Galaxy Stellar from Verizon. It's unrooted.

I can connect to a Wi-Fi network (input the network security key, etc). However, I can't use the network. I've tried it over three different networks and none of them worked. I've also done a factory reset still it doesn't work.

It worked just fine until a few days ago.

This is my wifi screen:

[image]

And this is my notification bar, where it says it's connected:

[image]

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?  You say you can connect, so how are you determining that it isn't using the wifi network?

Comment: And how are you determining it *did* connect successfully, and is not stuck at e.g. "obtaining IP address"?